Automatically downloading dependencies (SDL2) during builds with CMake
I was developing a very small game with C and SDL library. I was developing it on the Windows based machine so I prepared my CMakeLists.txt to automatically download SDL library from GitHub releases and place it under dependencies folder in the game directory.
With this way I was avoiding any of the manual work that I had to done to setup my dependencies.
Here's my current workflow step by step:

Check if the dependencies required are downloaded
Download the dependencies if they doesn't exists in dependencies folder
Extract the download dependencies

So, recently I changed my development environment to MacOS, I wonder if I can achieve the same workflow in MacOS. Just want to store dependencies inside project folder and automatically download them and extract them during build.
Here's my current CMakeLists.txt file that works perfectly for Windows.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(bomberman_remake C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)

# Update module path for easier script locating for CMake.
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

# Ensure that every single warning is enabled and every single warning is treated as error. (MSVC only)
if (MSVC)
    message(STATUS "Adding compile definitions for MSVC")
    add_compile_definitions(/Wall /WX)
endif ()

# Set the download URL for SDL library.
set(SDL2_DOWNLOAD_URL "https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/download/release-2.30.1/SDL2-devel-2.30.1-VC.zip")

# Set the extract directory for downloaded SDL library.
set(SDL2_EXTRACTION_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/SDL2")

# Download and extract SDL library.
message(STATUS "Trying to download and extract SDL library")
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SDL2 URL ${SDL2_DOWNLOAD_URL} SOURCE_DIR ${SDL2_EXTRACTION_DIRECTORY})
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SDL2)

# Add 'include' folder as header directory.
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

# Add SDL as include directory.
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

message(STATUS "Locating source files for executable linking")
add_executable(bomberman_remake src/main.c
        src/debugger.c
        src/game.c
        src/scene.c
        src/event_dispatcher.c
        src/player.c
        src/node.c
        src/map.c
        src/physics.c
        src/bomb.c
        src/asset_manager.c
        src/enemy.c
)

# Link the SDL library.
target_link_libraries(bomberman_remake PRIVATE ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

Thanks!
Here's the list of things that I tried to resolve this:

I tried to download .dmg release of SDL and extract it but it didn't work out because of linker errors
I could try to setup SDL on OS instead of project directory but I don't want to do that this way


Not a direct answer, but you may want to consider using vcpkg for automatic dependency management. It integrates with cmake and visual studio globally, and you have the choice of installing dependencies globally or within a given project's build folder.

FetchContent is a proper way for download dependencies. If it doesn't work for you, then show (add to the question post) the exact error message which you got. Do not ask us to guess what errors could be caused by a specific code.

@Tsyvarev I am not stating that FetchContent isn't working for me, it works but compiler seems like fails to link against.
Linker errors like:
Undefined reference to 'SDL_main'
I strongly think the question is pretty clear and not requiring anyone to guess something.

The archive SDL2-devel-2.30.1-VC.zip contains libraries suitable for Windows, they cannot be used on Mac. For some reason your FindSDL2.cmake script in cmake/ subdirectory don't report an error that it has failed to find suitable library, and it leaves variable SDL2_LIBRARIES to be empty. Do you still think that your question is complete and no one needs to guess?!

@Tsyvarev Yes, I am aware that I can not use SDL2-devel-2.30.1-VC.zip on MacOS.
Here's my current CMakeLists.txt file that works perfectly for Windows.
I think this statement clearly says I have this working on Windows and I am not trying to execute it on MacOS.
And yes, I still believe that my question is pretty clear. Sorry, I will not be reacting to your aggressive comments from now on.
I wish you great day.

Now I don't understand, is your question about the particular code or about a code in general? Normally, if a question post contains detailed code, we expect the question to be about fixing problems in that code. But now you say that you perfectly aware why your code doesn't work... If you ask about the problem in general, then possible approaches includes using 3d-party dependency managers like vcpkg or conan. FetchContent could be used too, but ... you already know that. It is not clear what you are asking for.
